# How to edit matplotlib plot labels from dataframe column?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe. The dataframe has dates as index and a variable. Consider as a toy example the following simple dataframe:

```
      date                   var1
      2001-03-01 00:00       1   
      2002-03-01 00:00       2    
      2003-03-01 00:00       3   
      2004-03-01 00:00       4
```

I want to plot `var1` versus the `date` using matplotlib. When I try the following:

```
  df["var1"].plot()
  plt.show()
```

I get the plot I want but on the `x` axis I have the full date/time (e.g. `2002-03-01 00:00`), while I would like to show just `2002`. Is there a (simple) way to do it?

Comment: Are the dates strings?

Comment: I am not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: ... You wrote the code making this I assume. If you can't tell us, then show us the code with you making the dataframe.

Comment: I think it is a string. The data come from another source, I didn't produce it, I just wanted to plot a variable.

Comment: @km1234 Tell us what `print type(df["date"][1])` says. This will tell us the type of the date.

Comment: @Akshat Thanks for the type hint, the output is <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html). The labels of `x` ticks are specified with the following line:

```
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

The first argument is the list with tick indexes and the second is list of labels. In Your case, You can get the dates from the first column with:

```
labels = df['date'].tolist()
```

where `df` is Your dataframe. Then You can perform operations on this list e.g. select just substrings with year:

```
>>> labels = ['2001-03-01 00:00', '2001-03-01 00:00']
>>> newlabels = [x[:4] for x in labels]
>>> newlabels
['2001', '2001']
```

and then use that list as labels with the first command.

So, combining everything:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
c1 = ['2001-03-01 00:00','2002-03-01 00:00','2003-03-01 00:00','2004-03-01 00:00']
c2 = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':c1,'var1':c2})
df['var1'].plot()
labels = df['date'].tolist()
newlabels = [x[:4] for x in labels]
plt.xticks(range(len(newlabels)), newlabels)
plt.show()
```

returns:

[image]